# Add / replace image to active element using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have some small divs set up in html. Inside the divs are logo's created by providing a url to the logo on the host site. I want to be able to change the image of the active div when it is clicked using JavaScript but it is just not working for me and I cant work out why. Im not exactly sure if I am using the correct syntax. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried setting a background image using CSS and adding the class but the logo appears on top of the image I am trying to show.

```
if((tileNumber == mine1) || (tileNumber == mine2) || (tileNumber == mine3) ||(tileNumber == mine4)){
        document.activeElement.classList.add("explode");
        document.activeElement.src = "../images/bomb.gif";
        xplode = xplode+1;
       if(xplode == 3){window.location.href="gameover.php"};
   }
```

What I am seeing is the background color changing due to the CSS class being applied but I am not seeing the image at all. The logo on the div is also still showing. I really just want to be able to swap the current image for the bomb image on click. Thanks.

Comment: In order to change an image using `.src`, `document.activeElement` has to be an `<img/>` element. I doubt that it is since `document.activeElement` is the element that has focus and `<img/>` elements can't gain focus.

Comment: Hi Titus, thank you for your comment. I appreciate you taking a look. ActiveElement is actually an image element. I’m not understanding what you mean by activeElement being the active element that has focus. 
The way the page works is that a series of logos are loaded onto a page, using links to the logos in MySQL. When users click on the logo image 1 of 3 things happen. They get a message on the “tile” and the logo disappears, or, the “tile” changes background color, or, the logo images changes to another image “bomb”. Right now the last function is not working. Thanks again.

Comment: Is there another way to go about achieving my result?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what `document.activeElement` is. If you want to change a `<img/>` element's `src` when it is clicked, add a click listener to it and use `event.target` to reference it where `event` is the click event.

Comment: Hi Titus, thank you so very much. It worked. My JavaScript needs a refresher.

Comment: Perhaps you can remind me how to mark your last comment as the correct answer? I’m on a small device and I don’t see the option. Thanks.

Comment: That was just a comment not an answer, if it was helpful, you can click the up arrow to the left of it to indicate that.